# SSL error downloading NLTK data on Manjaro Linux

Tags: ssl, download, nltk

I am trying to download the stopwords library using nltk but as the title suggests the SSL certificate check fails when i try using "nltk.download('stopwords')".

I have read the already posted solutions but the method where they say to use Install Certificate.command just doesn't work for me since there is no such directory in my file system.I am using Manjaro Linux and have installed Anaconda from the pamac itself.

`import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')`

The error is

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
False
```